# A variable of two types

Tags: c#, json, typescript, json-deserialization

I need to read an JSON object from TypeScript, which has a variable names `prop` which of two types, either `Identifier`  or `Expression` to C#. TypeScript can have a variable with multiple types (with its union type feature), e.g., `prop` is defined as

```
var property:Identifier | Expression
```

I am reading the JSON object string from C# with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, e.g.,

```
Object facebookFriends = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Object>(JSON_Object);
```

How should I declare a variable of two types in C#? Or should I just use `object` (i.e., declare as `Object property`)?

Comment: When you do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, you'll need the actual `type` of the object. And in general, `C#` is a strongly typed language, there is nothing like *"variable of two types"*. You can use `object`, or `dynamic` in some cases, but they might cause other issues later. For your case, you might create a wrapper type with the two types included, and populate the required one from `JavaScript`, but hard to suggest without complete context.

Comment: Thanks, what kinds of other issues you can perceive?

Comment: All that comes with loosing type safety, like type mismatch at runtime. For `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, you can use [dynamic](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm), but without knowing the type it'll be hard I guess.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object", Can you clarify what `Identifier` or `Expression` mean here? I suspect one of these isn't really following JSON syntax. Can you show examples of both?

Answer (score 3):

If the property can have either of these two formats:

```
{ "prop": "identifier" }
{ "prop": { "complex": "object" } }
```

ie. either a simple string or a more complex object you can solve this by using `dynamic` to accept the parsed `prop` value, and extra properties to return either the identifier or the complex object. Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonStrings = new[]
    {
        "{ \"prop\": \"identifier\" }",
        "{ \"prop\": { \"complex\": \"object\" } }"
    };

    jsonStrings.Select(json => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json)).Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        _Complex = new Lazy<Complex>(GetComplex);
    }

    [JsonProperty("prop")]
    public dynamic prop { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Identifier => prop as string;

    private readonly Lazy<Complex> _Complex;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Complex Complex => _Complex.Value;

    private Complex GetComplex()
    {
        if (!(prop is JObject))
            return null;

        return ((JObject)prop).ToObject<Complex>();
    }
}

public class Complex
{
    public string complex { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image: example output]

A different approach would be to create your own types to handle the multiple outputs and again use a secondary property to evaluate what you actually got from the json:

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonStrings = new[]
    {
        "{ \"prop\": \"identifier\" }",
        "{ \"prop\": { \"complex\": \"object\" } }"
    };

    jsonStrings.Select(json => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json)).Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("prop")]
    public dynamic prop { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public PropertyValue Property
    {
        get
        {
            if (prop is string)
                return new IdentifierProperty(prop as string);
            return new ExpressionProperty(((JObject)prop).ToObject<Expression>());
        }
    }
}

public abstract class PropertyValue
{
}

public class IdentifierProperty : PropertyValue
{
    public IdentifierProperty(string identifier)
    {
        Identifier = identifier;
    }

    public string Identifier { get; }

    public override string ToString() => Identifier;
}

public class ExpressionProperty : PropertyValue
{
    public ExpressionProperty(Expression expression)
    {
        Expression = expression;
    }

    public Expression Expression { get; }

    public override string ToString() => Expression.ToString();
}

public class Expression
{
    public string complex { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"complex: {complex}";
}
```

Output:

[image: second example output]

Comment: Thanks, let me response to you later after I test the approach