# How would I represent the following JSON layout as a C# object?

Tags: c#, json

I am a little confused as to how to represent this as a C# class. I want to deserialize the below JSON file into a C# class.

I have an idea but kind of lost looking at, I think I am missing the idea a little!

I have this so far:

```
public class CountrySetting
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Flag {get;set;}
}

public class Setting
{
   public string Type {get;set;}
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public List<LabelSetting> Label {get;set;}
}

public class LabelSetting 
{
   public string Key {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

The JSON layout is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "USA",
    "flag": "usa.jpg",    
  },
  {
    "name": {      
      "en": "Layout",
      "es": "Diseño"      
    },
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "enabled",
        "label": {
          "en": "Please Select One or More"          
        }
      }
    ]
  }    
]
```

Comment: Is the shown JSON the true representation of what you are trying to parse? It is an object array with differing object definitions.

Comment: What produced such bad JSON? You have an array of dissimilar objects. In C#, `object[]` is about as close as you can get without going to `dynamic`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395609/a-variable-of-two-types

Comment: What is that JSON supposed to represent? The two objects in the array are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` property of the first item in the array is a different kind of object to what it is in the 2nd object.

```
[
  {
    "name": "USA",
    (...)
  },
  {
    "name": {      
      "en": "Layout",
      "es": "Diseño"      
    },
    (...)
  }    
]
```

While this is valid json you cannot deserialise it to one class.
You can still get the values though.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
(...)

var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
var one = jArr[0].ToObject<Type1>();
var two = jArr[1].ToObject<Type2>();
```

---

## Models

```
 public class Country
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string en { get; set; }
        public string es { get; set; }
    }

    public class Label
    {
        public string en { get; set; }
    }

    public class Setting
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Label label { get; set; }
    }

    public class Something
    {
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public List<Setting> settings { get; set; }
    }
```

## Test code

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var json = @"[
  {
    ""name"": ""USA"",
    ""flag"": ""usa.jpg"",    
  },
  {
    ""name"": {      
      ""en"": ""Layout"",
      ""es"": ""Diseño""      
    },
    ""settings"": [
      {
        ""type"": ""checkbox"",
        ""id"": ""enabled"",
        ""label"": {
          ""en"": ""Please Select One or More""          
        }
      }
    ]
  }    
]";

        var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
        var c = jArr[0].ToObject<Country>();
        var s = jArr[1].ToObject<Something>();

        Console.WriteLine(c.flag);
        Console.WriteLine(s.name.es);
        Console.WriteLine(s.settings[0].label.en);
    }
```

Result

```
usa.jpg
Diseño
Please Select One or More
```

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to create the objects. You can use https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp to create both models with C# capitalisation.

For exemple:

```
public partial class Country
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("flag")]
        public string Flag { get; set; }
    }
```